# Use of NASA signage in the Martian?

Tags: the-martian

NASA signage has been used on most props and sets in the movie *The Martian*.

Firstly, why does NASA allow its name to be attached to for profit ventures when it itself is a government agency?

Secondly, does NASA play an active role in any of the films that it grants the use of its signage to, such as consulting or rather just supervision?

Thirdly, does NASA make any money out of such collaborations?

Comment: [WHY NASA HELPED RIDLEY SCOTT CREATE ‘THE MARTIAN’ FILM](http://www.popsci.com/why-nasa-helped-ridley-scott-create-martian-film-and-what-means-future-sci-fi-space-movies).

Comment: [How NASA and Ridley Scott Collaborated to Make 'The Martian'](http://mentalfloss.com/article/69351/how-nasa-and-ridley-scott-collaborated-make-martian)

Comment: [NASA Is Loving The Martian’s Triumphant Success](http://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2015/10/nasa-martian-movie/408844/)

Comment: "*NASA even got in on the film. While the government agency can't support a private enterprise, NASA experts consulted on the movie, and production has worked very closely with NASA's Jet Propulsion Lab officials, Weir said.
NASA also gave permission for the film to use the copyrighted — and coveted — NASA logo on its costumes, as you can see in these screenshots from the trailer:*" - http://www.techinsider.io/the-martian-best-space-sci-fi-movie-2015-8

Comment: *"'Nasa is a large, slow, federal organisation that has no vested interest in giving you the logo. Gravity wanted to use it and it took so long that they had to digitally remove the logo from the trailers because they still hadn’t got permission at that point. But with The Martian, the studio said they had never got permission handed back so quickly.’*" - http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/the-martian/andy-weir-author-interview/

Comment: I heard (in an interview or commentary) that *Farscape* wanted to use the NASA logo, but NASA wanted script approval on **every episode**, even though NASA wouldn't be a large part of the series. The producers opted to make up "IASA" instead.

Comment: *"And Green’s work on The Martian has had very real implications for the nonfictional NASA Mars program. He asked Ochoa, his human spaceflight counterpart, to detail him a Johnson Space Center employee for one year. She assigned Rick Davis, a NASA veteran who formerly served as the primary communicator between Mission Control and the International Space Station. Davis was tasked with spearheading a list of places to put humans on Mars. That way, NASA can tell the public “here’s what the real sites look like, and here’s why we’re looking at them,”*" - http://www.astronomy.com/bonus/martian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NASA can deny movies using their logo and name.

> This general permission does not extend to use of the NASA insignia logo (the blue "meatball" insignia), the retired NASA logotype (the red "worm" logo) and the NASA seal. These images may not be used by persons who are not NASA employees or on products (including Web pages) that are not NASA-sponsored.

[- NASA Guidelines](http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/guidelines/index.html)

Usually they want to give script approval before they allow movies to use their name and logo.  In the case of Farscape, they did not allow their logo to be used, so the movie had to make the necessary changes:

> Crichton was going to be a NASA astronaut, but NASA requested script approval for the use of their logos, so "NASA" became the "IASA". ("Cool Farscape Facts" - Starburst Edition DVD v1.1)

[- Farscape Wiki](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Premiere#References)

NASA's excitement and fondness of the movie The Martian is well documented and reported.  As such, it is very likely they gave script approval (especially because there was no drama and close to reality... in a movie kind of way).

Comment: Related: Military/DOD and Movies. http://www.businessinsider.com/phil-strub-controls-hollywoods-military-access-2014-3