# What protocols did NASA stop using during Apollo 9 that the CNSA is still using?

Tags: plot-explanation, alternate-version, the-martian

In the amazing film, ***"The Martian"***, there is a montage sequence where everyone is figuring out how to get the Hermes resupplied for it's rescue mission of Space Pirate Mark Watney.

During this sequence, there is a scene where a NASA employee is, through a translator, telling a China National Space Administration that they are using obsolete ideas:

> All due respect to your CNSA protocol... but we haven't done things that way... since Apollo 9.
>   [To Translator] Did he get that?

Apollo 9 being March 3, 1969, almost 60 years before the movie is set in (2020s~2030s).

**What protocols is he critiquing here?**

**And considering Chinese Government restrictions on speech in movies (disparaging the Chinese Government vis-a-vis their national space program), how did this line make it into the final film? Or is it excluded from the Chinese release?**

Had the movie likewise disparaged NASA in any way, [they would have lost NASA support and the access to the NASA logos](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50259/use-of-nasa-signage-in-the-martian?rq=1), here in the US.

Answer (score 3):

The exact protocol in question is not defined, neither in the movie nor the book.

By Apollo 9, many procedures had been performed and documented; rendezvous, docking, transfers, launch windows, etc. but the protocols were no doubt tightened to increase safety margins. It could be any of these protocols.

If I were to guess, I'd say it would be something about [launch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_window) or [transfer timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit). These are things that are incredibly specific and difficult to correctly predict months in advance.

Comment: Apollo 9 didn't leave earth orbit, but it was NASA's first docking of 2 manned vehicles.

Comment: Probably the docking into an open, manned airlock.